# How to use OAuth2 with GraphQL Spring Webclient

Tags: java, spring, oauth-2.0, graphql, graphql-java

I'm using the [GraphQL Spring Webclient](https://github.com/graphql-java-kickstart/graphql-spring-webclient) and followed the readme, but can't seem to get OAuth 2 to work. I'm trying to get auth from the keycloak server to be able to query the GraphQL API. The readme only mentioned to put the OAuth 2 info into the app yml file, so I'm not sure if I needed to do anything else.

```
graphql:
  client:
    url: 
    oauth2:
      client-id: 
      client-secret: 
      token-uri: 
      authorization-uri: 
      scope: 
      authorization-grant-type: 
      client-name:
```

When sending a request to the GraphQL API, I end up getting 401 unauthorized. I put breakpoints in the `GraphQLWebClientAutoConfiguration` class as well as the `OAuth2ClientRegistrationRepositoryConfiguration` class from the `package graphql.kickstart.spring.webclient.boot`. Both appear to be working as intended, although I did notice that the `provider` and `issuer-uri` were null. I wasn't sure if these were required and honestly not sure what I would put in those spots.

When digging into the 401 error, there wasn't any bearer token in the header or body. I'm not sure if I need to create the token or just attach it somehow.

I wasn't sure if I needed to create my own `SecurityConfig` class, but when I tried doing it, I was running into `ClientRegistrationRepository` not found errors. They were similar errors to when I left the `client-id` and `client-secret` fields empty in the yaml, so I figured I didn't need a `SecurityConfig` file if the `GraphQL Spring Webclient` took care of it for me.

If someone could help point me in the right direction or provide examples, that would be much appreciated.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.graphql-java-kickstart</groupId>
        <artifactId>graphql-webclient-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Did you see any errors in your logs in either your client, server or Keycloak?